# Sort JavaScript array of object based on date and date difference

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

Please help me to sort the array (Array should be sorted based on sdate as well as difference of edate and sdate )

Input Array object:-

```
[{sdate:'03/20/2017',edate:'03/21/2017',id:1},
{sdate:'03/20/2017',edate:'03/24/2017',id:2},
{sdate:'03/20/2017',edate:'03/20/2017',id:3},
{sdate:'03/19/2017',edate:'03/20/2017',id:4}]
```

Output Array object :-

```
[{sdate:'03/19/2017',edate:'03/20/2017',id:4},
 {sdate:'03/20/2017',edate:'03/24/2017',id:2},
 {sdate:'03/20/2017',edate:'03/21/2017',id:1},
 {sdate:'03/20/2017',edate:'03/20/2017',id:3}]
```

What I have tried :

```
 arrObj.sort(function(a,b){
    return new Date(a.sdate) - new Date(b.sdate);
 });
```

It only returns sorted array based on `sdate` but if `sdate` is same then object should come first which has higher differences of days `(edate -sdate)`

Comment: Please put comments before down voting :)

Comment: I didn't downvote. But I believe this is far simpler for such a rep user and also, this is like asking for code rather than what you tried. Do you agree? `:)`

Comment: What have you attempted so far?

Comment: I need sorted array based on not only start date but date difference as well

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this should do the trick :) 
here its sorting by edate (reverse), if sdates are the same..

```js
Arr = [{sdate:'03/20/2017',edate:'03/21/2017',id:1},
{sdate:'03/20/2017',edate:'03/24/2017',id:2},
{sdate:'03/20/2017',edate:'03/20/2017',id:3},
{sdate:'03/19/2017',edate:'03/20/2017',id:4}];

Arr.sort(function(a, b) {
  if(a.sdate === b.sdate){
   return new Date(b.edate) - new Date(a.edate);
  }
  return new Date(a.sdate) - new Date(b.sdate);
});

console.log(Arr);
```

Answer (score 0):

My two cents:

```
[{
    sdate: '03/20/2017',
    edate: '03/21/2017',
    id: 1
}, {
    sdate: '03/20/2017',
    edate: '03/24/2017',
    id: 2
}, {
    sdate: '03/20/2017',
    edate: '03/20/2017',
    id: 3
}, {
    sdate: '03/19/2017',
    edate: '03/20/2017',
    id: 4
}].sort(function(a, b) {
    var sdateA = +new Date(a.sdate)
      , sdateB = +new Date(b.sdate)
      , edateA = +new Date(a.edate)
      , edateB = +new Date(b.edate);

    return sdateA === sdateB ? edateB - edateA : sdateA - sdateB;
})
```